# How to store input from TextField into an array of Strings in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, input, textfield

I have a Textfield and a button. Wenn the button is pressed, a function is triggered that stores the items that are typed in the TextField into an Array and then outputs the current contents of the Array to the console. How to store the input from the TextField into an array of strings? I've just started learning Swift and need your help. Thanks a lot in  advance!

```
 @IBOutlet weak var inputEntered: UITextField!


@IBAction func buttonAddToList(_ sender: UIButton) {

    var shoppingList: [String] = []

    let item = inputEntered.text
    shoppingList.append(item)

    for product in shoppingList {
        print(product)
    }

}
```

Comment: Please post code that you have tried - you'll not get replies from people on Stack Overflow unless you show you have had a go at it yourself and where you get stuck.

Comment: please post your code that you tried ?

Comment: I've just edited the post.

Comment: you need to declare your array as a property of your view controller. Move `var shoppingList: [String] = []` out of your method `buttonAddToList`

Comment: You need also to force unwrap the text property `let item = inputEntered.text!`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store all inputs declare your strings outside the function

```swift
@IBOutlet weak var inputEntered: UITextField!
var shoppingList: [String] = [] // our holder of strings

@IBAction func buttonAddToList(_ sender: UIButton) {

    if let item = inputEntered.text, item.isEmpty == false { // need to make sure we have something here
        shoppingList.append(item) // store it in our data holder
    }
    inputEntered.text = nil // clean the textfield input

    for product in shoppingList {
        print(product) // prints the items currently in the list
    }
}
```

The flow will be, everytime you click the button it adds that to the list and remove the text input value so it feels like you are ready for the next input/item in the list.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was very helpful.  Do you know which  methods  could delete duplicates from the console?  For loop generates duplicates that I don't need.

Comment: Update: To avoid duplicates generated by the for loop  I wrote just print(shoppingList.last!) instead of for loop.